# Opacity when hovering DIV or other Element

Tags: html, css

I want to apply `opacity: 1;` to a Paragraph when hovering over itself (I have figured that out) **and** when I hover the header above it.

This is my CSS

```
.testH {
    font-family: impact;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.testP {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

#testHdiv:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.testP:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

My HTML

```
    <div id="testHdiv"><h1 class="testH"><b>< ></b></h1>
    <p class="testP">Text and text, more text<br>Bla bla bla bla</p>
    </div>
```

So, as you can see I try to get the opacity from the paragraphs current 0.5, to 1 when hovering the Div - my idea is: being able to hover a "box"/the div, and the text becomming less transparent. Though I think the `opacity` on the hover of the Div does not Work as the div is defined a Div, not text, and therefor can't be transparent?

I have been struggling with this for a while now. But I am basically wanting something like this: http://demo.web3canvas.com/themeforest/flathost/onepage/index.html#testimonials, where you hover within range of the text and it is being zoomed - in this case, just with opacity.

Comment: Not really sure what you want here.

Comment: You want opacity the paragraph, when div are hovered, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a class to the `<p>` or just, use an operator to set the `:hover` to paragraph.

**Example:**

```
#testHdiv:hover > p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g97pusex/1/

Comment: Didn't know you could put a simple '>' in there - thank you.

Comment: It's not just a simple `>`, that is for a direct child of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
#testHdiv:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

To be like that:

```
#testHdiv:hover p{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to apply the opacity to the `p` element, not the div. According to your provided style, you can change it to this:

```
.testH {
    font-family: impact;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.testP {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

#testHdiv:hover .testH {
    opacity: 1;
}

#testHdiv:hover .testP {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Notice how the `:hover` selector is applied to the div, but the style is applied to the `p` element `.testP`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hover the div and on hover it affect the paragraph opacity change your CSS to:

```
#testHdiv:hover  .testP{
     opacity: 1;
```

}

Comment: You asked a question in your answer. This is better meant for a comment.

Comment: I changed the copy. Thanks Wes Foster.